# Iterate through array in Kotlin to replace elements

Tags: arrays, kotlin, for-loop

I'm learning Kotlin and I want to iterate through array to replace some elements.

To change something inside elements I do this:

```
if (arr != null){         // Kotlin doesn't like NullReferenceException
    for(elem in arr) {    // for each element
        elem.property++;  // do something with element
    }
}
```

But when I want to replace element at some position I have to do this:

```
if (arr != null){                           // Kotlin doesn't like NullReferenceException
    if (arr.size > 0) {                     // check size
        for (i in 0..arr.size - 1) {        // for all elements
            if (i == 5){                    // if something
                arr[i] = buildNewElement(); // replace element
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a bit ugly.

Does Kotlin offer something nicer or something that could reduce lines of code?

Comment: Is it a requirement for it to be done in place rather than making a new array? Like expectations for the size to be very large?

Comment: Otherwise, this is what `map()` is for.

Comment: @DonBranson In this particular case I can have up to 500 elements, about 100 bytes each, and code runs on battery operated Android device. But it would be good to know both approaches.

Comment: @DonBranson I forgot to add, that this array is bound with UI and rewriting/replacing will consume a lot of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, because you are using kotlin you should rarely need to do a `if (someVal != null)` check. Nullable types have a safe call operator that you can use instead: `?.`

If the requirement is to keep the array in place, consider using forEachIndexed (with the usual caveats about modifying an array in-place):

```
arr?.forEachIndexed { i, value ->
    arr[i] = buildNewElement()
}
```

If you don't need to use value, you can rename it to `_`

If you do not need to do this in-place and can generate a new array, you should instead consider `map`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed :) And I know about safe call operator, but in this case it was more clean to use old null check, because I wanted to avoid doing a few other operations not directly related to this nullable object.

Comment: I have extra question. Can we add something like filter to this? I need to replace object only when `arr[i].someProp== someVar`?

Comment: Certainly, you can put whatever you want in the code block. So if you only want to do this when certain conditions are met, just put some if-statement in the block. It's not really any different from a standard for-loop.

Comment: Using of `?.` and `?.let` instead of  good-old-null-checks is good practice in kotlin. Sooner or later you'll encounter nullable variables/properties that stays nullable after your null checking and you'll be surprised by the need of all this ugly `!!` in code.